# Automatically styling new chunks of information added to web page

Tags: html, css

I am creating a front end page which would get data from various sources.
I want data sources to be dynamically added without code changes, and for that would providing an ability to add new sources url on fly.
However, some of these data sources might need a different css styling like tables.
I want an ability to provide css styles without making code changes.

Is there a good way to store css/or provide styling abilities ?
I might be fishing here but I am thinking if there is a standard way of doing this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure the title matches your question...

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected the title.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand . You need to have to add these dynamic sources to a database table . Then when fetching data from each source you need to write code such that it decorates each item in its own way by detecting what source it is from . Hope that helps .

Comment: Yeah this is what I am looking for. Is there some library that provides some similar functionality.

Comment: I don't think so . You have to write it yourself . It is not that hard too .

Comment: One think that could help is using a templating engine like mustache. It would take the json data and a template and render it. I can store this template somewhere in configuration.